# Calling service from another module in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

When I try to import test from ConfigAppProviderModule, I'm getting the error of "has no exported member test". Is I'm making any mistake in writing service with config in module.

```
import { NgModule ,InjectionToken,Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export const ConfigToken = new InjectionToken<string>('ConfigToken');

class test {
  config:any;
  constructor(config){
    this.config = config; 
  }

  a(){
    console.log("this.config",this.config);
  }

}

const ConfigAppProvider = {
  provide: test,
  useFactory:  (config) => {
    return new test(config);
  },
  deps: [ ConfigToken]
};

@NgModule({
  providers: [ ConfigAppProvider ],
})
export class ConfigAppProviderModule {
  static initializeApp(config) {
    return {
      ngModule: ConfigAppProviderModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: ConfigToken, useValue: config }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not export the const ConfigAppProvider

```
export const ConfigAppProvider = {
  provide: test,
  useFactory:  (config) => {
    return new test(config);
  },
  deps: [ CsbaseAppConfigToken ]
};
```

Similarly

```
export class Test
```

and also you are not decorating it with `@Injectable()`.

Comment: Why I'm need to export the const ConfigAppProvider and decorating class test with @Injectable() when I'm declaring it in a providers array of @NgModule decorater